# ASP Button | UpdatePanel Trigger issue

Tags: asp.net

I have an issue with asp button within updatepanel:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
                    <section class="panel">
                        <header class="panel-heading">
                            Oceny twoich uczniów
                      <div class="panel-actions">
                          <asp:Button ID="refreshPageButton" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-setting" />
                          <!-- <a id="refreshPage" href="index.html#" class="btn-setting"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></a>-->
                      </div>
                        </header>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="panel-content">
                                <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
                                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="StudentsGradesUpdatePanel" runat="server">
                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                        <fieldset>
                                            <asp:GridView ID="marksGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" CssClass="table table-hover" UseAccessibleHeader="true">
                                            </asp:GridView>
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                    <Triggers>
                                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="refreshPageButton" />
                                    </Triggers>
                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

I need to somehow transform my aspbutton to look like:

```
<a id="refreshPage" href="index.html#" class="btn-setting"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></a>
```

I've tried LinkButton and html button, but they're not accepted as updatepanel trigger.

Any clever ideas? :)

Comment: Why not a PostBackTrigger??

Comment: I have to do it without refreshing the page